# Magento Product Images not showing on Category and Product views

Tags: caching, memcached, apc, magento-1.12

Magento Enterprise 1.12.0.2

In our development environment, our product images are not showing up on either the category or the product views. It's attempting to access cached images and all the caches have been flushed, both at the file and the Magento levels.

We migrated from an instance with APC and Memcached. On that instance, Full Page Caching went through APC. We are not using APC or Memcached on our development environment.

For clarity, if you had been able to go to a product page, the product image would not show. If you looked at the source, you'd see http://www.domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/135x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/n/a/navigator.jpg. If you took out the cache path and looked for http://www.domain.com/media/catalog/product/n/a/navigator.jpg, you would find it. If you looked in the media directory on our machine, you wouldn't have found any cache files.

For whatever reason, the images now display as expected on the first test instance. However, when I copied the test instance, I have the issue again on the new instance. What might I be missing?

Comment: Is your media directory writable?

Comment: 770 on media directories

Comment: Did you ever fix this??

Comment: We are not currently experiencing this issue but I do not know what resolution was found, if any.